# Start add2ress of the page in memory?

Tags: operating-system

If a process references the virtual address `0x100F3557`, the values of the three fields, in which the virtual address can be splitted, are:

```
Offset = 0x557
Page Table = 0x0F3
Page Directory = 0x040
```

The Page Table Entry of this address has the value `0x71248021`.

What is my start address of the page in memory?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming x86 paging the page table entry consist of the (physical) address of the frame the page is mapped into plus some control information. The later occupies the lower 12 bit of the entry, which are the last 3 digits of your hexadecimal value. Thus

- frame address = `0x71248000`
- control information = `0x021`

The [control information](http://wiki.osdev.org/Paging#Page_Table) here tells us that this page is

- *present*, bit 0 set, thus there is an active mapping.
- *read-only*, bit 1 unset
- *user mode accessible*, bit 2 unset
- (*write back* cached, bit 3 unset)
- (*cached*, bit 4 unset)
- accessed, but not written to (bit 5 set, bit 6 unset)
- (not a *global page*, bit 8 unset)

Thus, assuming a read operation, the process will access address `0x71248000 | 0x557 == 0x71248557`, with `0x557` being the offset extracted from the virtual address.